# ZUUL Forwarding Error when invoking the service

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty, ibm-was, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a EUREKA , ZUUL and a sample ATOMIC Service deployed to WAS Liberty Profile.
When I try to hit the proxy url for ATOMIC Service I get Forwarding error.

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error

            at             org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward    (RibbonRoutingFilter.java:145)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SRV.8.2: RequestWrapper objects must    extend ServletRequestWrapper or HttpServletRequestWrapper
        at     com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.ServletUtil.unwrapRequest(ServletUtil.java:91)
        at     com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.ServletUtil.unwrapRequest(ServletUtil.java:63)
```

The complete stack trace is at,

https://github.com/bsridhar123/ZUUL/blob/master/logs/PROXY_ATOMIC.txt

I have shared the code for these services  in the github repos.

--For ZUUL Reverse Proxy Service
https://github.com/bsridhar123/ZUUL

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Two things to check - 1. If your RequestWrapper correctly extends the required class. 2. if you are not packaging servlet.jar file inside of application (remove if yes)

Comment: what is the url that you are hitting just wanted to know to see if there is something with the configuration.